What if ScheduledExecutorService fails?
What if put all the task on ScheduledExecutorService, but then if server goes off or server get updates and restarts there task which i have give to threads will be lost is there , any solution for this
How to persist data which i have put on ScheduledExecutorService.

Don't. If you have those requirements don't use ScheduledExecutorService Use something like JobRunR or Quartz then.

The implementation(s) of ScheduledExecutorService provided with Java remember their submitted tasks in-memory only.
When your app exits, all the submitted and executing-but-incomplete tasks vanish, poof . Or worse, if you did not shut them down gracefully, the threads backing the thread-pool may continue indefinitely, like zombies ‍♂️.
If you need to track any remaining tasks that are incomplete or await execution, either use another tool, or manage the tracking yourself.
Tracking yourself is not difficult. Here is one solution…
As you submit tasks, you would record their identifier in a database. As the last step of the task‘s work, the task would delete or modify the database record matching its own identifier.
On startup, your app would query the database for tasks not yet completed. Then recreate those task objects, and submit to the new ScheduledExecutorService.
In this scenario, a robust database engine such as H2 or Postgres handles the challenges of concurrency, and of resilience in the face of an interruption like a crash or power-outage.
I suppose you could write your own implementation of ScheduledExecutorService to handle this persistent task tracking. But I don’t know if I would bother.
